# Retrieve empty Set<String> from userPreferences

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
Set<String> test = C.userPreferences.getStringSet("default", Here);
```

And what I'd like to know is how to make Here an empty string set by default instead of null because I need to `test.add(String)` after and I can't do that if test is null.

I tried `Collections.emptySet()` but failed with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Answer (score 2):

Just test if test is null right after your call:

```
Set<String> test = C.userPreferences.getStringSet("default", Here);    
if (test == null)
    test = new HashSet<String>();
```

The `HashSet` class is just an implementation of the `Set` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
C.userPreferences.getStringSet("default", new HashSet<String>());
```

Of course, you can use whichever implementation of Set you prefer (TreeSet, HashSet, ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> temp = C.userPreferences.getStringSet("default", Here==null ? new HashSet<String>() : Here) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more simplistic way is as follows:

```
Set<String> savedStringSet = myPrefs.getStringSet("my_saved_strings", Collections.<String>emptySet());
```

Works perfectly.